# Wordpress Automatic Login for a username

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to implement automatic login for a wordpress username which already exists.
I am using wp_signon function as follows:

```
add_action('after_setup_theme' , 'auto_login');
function auto_login(){
    $creds = array();
    $creds['user_login'] = "tester";
    $creds['user_password'] = "password123";
    $creds['remember'] = false;
    $user = wp_signon( $creds, true );

    if ( is_wp_error($user) )
       echo $user->get_error_message();
}
```

I am not able to understand why i am not able to see dashboard page for user "tester"
I am not getting any errors or warnings.I have used this code in functions.php of the theme.

Comment: What's the reason for hooking to after_setup_theme? Are you sure this is the right hook?

Comment: @henrywright I used after_setup_theme hook because till this time user is not authenticated.